# Is it safe to launch an AMI based from a snapshot?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have created a snapshot based on the running instance. This instance is perfectly fine, I just want to create a separate instance where I can play around or experiment. Now,  after I created the snapshot, I created the AMI based on the snapshot. Now my question is, when I launch the AMI as an instance using the `Launch instance from AMI` button, will it affect my original instance, the one that is currently running? I just need to make sure that I will not affect in any way, the original instance, to avoid damages or anything that might affect the operation of the original instance.
[image]

Comment: T L;DR AMI wont affect the original instance. But I do have a question

`want to create a separate instance where I can play around or experiment.`　
When you say you want to play around or experiment, is it correct to assume you want to use the same data stored inside your running ec2?　Based on this answer It will give a clear picture on what will help you the most？

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yes, precisely. It's already a working website. I just want to have a copy of it, point to a separate domain where I can play around with it. I inherited this project and I have no idea how to create a staging site for it, so i thought the fastest way is to create a duplicate of the running instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Will it affect my original instance, the one that is currently running?**

No.

An Amazon EBS Snapshot is a **copy of an Amazon EBS Volume**. Think of it like a backup copy of the disk.

When you create an AMI from a Snapshot, the AMI just points to the Snapshot. Then, when you launch an instance using the AMI, it associates the Snapshot with the new EBS boot disk on the instance. When the EC2 instance goes to access some data on that boot volume, it will retrieve the block from the EBS snapshot.

Any changes made to the boot volume will be stored on the EBS Volume without impacting the Snapshot or the AMI.

The original instance is not involved in any of this -- the contents of its disk is not impacted by creating the Snapshot or using the Snapshot as an AMI.

By the way, **taking a Snapshot of a 'running instance'** means that not all data might have been written to disk. When the Snapshot is used to create an AMI and the instance is booted from that AMI, the disk will be a reflection of the original instance at the moment the original Snapshot was taken. This is similar to pulling the power cord out of a PC -- the next time it boots it might might take a little longer since it was not shutdown correctly. To avoid this situation, when an **AMI** is created from a running instance there is a default option to **reboot** the instance -- the underlying snapshot is then created after the instance was shutdown and before it was booted again. This makes a more reliable disk image.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for this. I might have to get back to you once I point my domain to the new instance. Quick question, will my new instance contain the data of the original instance, except of course the newly added data on the original instance. My goal is to play around the new instance and treat it as the staging site of my site.

Answer (score 1):

Launching the AMI won't affect the original ec2.
AMI's can potentially be pretty expensive. You would likely be better off spinning up a basic ec2 and installing what you need in userdata.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Here is a snippet from a CloudFormation template that will spin up an ec2 and run some commands.

cfn-init would be something to check out if you really want to get into it with deploying ec2.

```
  jumpHostEC2:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      BlockDeviceMappings: # the secondary drive is listed in volumes to tag it so it will get backed up.
        - DeviceName: /dev/sda1
          Ebs:
            VolumeSize: 20
            VolumeType: gp2
      #IamInstanceProfile: <some profile>
      ImageId: ami-00xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: dev-instances
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - sg-xxxxxxxxx
        - sg-xxxxxxxxx
      SubnetId: subnet-xxxxxxxxx
      Tags: 
        - Key: Name
          Value: jumphost
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64:
          #!/bin/bash
          set -e
          apt-get update
          DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qq --no-install-recommends python-pip libssl-dev libffi-dev \
          wget dpkg-dev debhelper build-essential
          rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
          apt-get update -y
          apt-get install -y python-pip
```

Comment: Why do you say that AMIs are expensive? An AMI is basically an Amazon EBS Snapshot with additional metadata. An EBS Snapshot is a copy of data on an Amazon EBS Volume. They only record what has changed since a previous snapshot. Therefore, if an instance is launched from an existing AMI (eg Amazon Linux 2) and an AMI is then made of the instance, the snapshot underlying the AMI is actually quite tiny -- it only stores what has changed on the volume compared to the original AMI. Snapshots cost 5c/GB/month, thus that is also the cost of AMIs -- and only for data that has _changed_.

Comment: I should have said, a custom AMI is more expensive than using an existing one. It doesn't have to be expensive...

Comment: @ddtraveller not the answer I am looking for, but thank you, this is helpful later as I get acquainted with AWS.

Answer (score -2):

> will it affect my original instance, the one that is currently running?

No.

> I just need to make sure that I will not affect in any way, the original instance, to avoid damages or anything that might affect the operation of the original instance.

Indeed, you have to ensure, to have separate accounting for the separate instances, as otherwise, credits go out faster because you use more resources und then credits are being spend faster and this will affect all running instances. Separate that part first.

Apart from that, in general no. However, keep in mind, that there are no backups or guarantees and you're operating in a running, complex system. The next instance you launch might just be that instance that brings complete AWS down due to some unforeseen configuration bug. Very unlikely, but as the systems are interconnected through and dependent on AWS, you might hit the Jackpot and bring a large share of the US Internet Market down just by chance.

Comment: What? Sorry, but saying that one user's usage of an instance impacts other instances is utterly incorrect. Instances are network-isolated and can't impact each other. If you are referring to the AWS backplane, the actions of a user are not relevant.

Comment: It must be your reading, we have this only as the single corn of sand in the desert it is, you are absolutely overstating things. Next time the northern region switches light out, enjoy your network isolation. @JohnRotenstein